# Vimeo not playing in fullscreen web app

Tags: ios, html, ipad, video, vimeo

Developing a simple web app that has vimeo embed in it. When visiting the app in Safari in normal mode, it will play, however, when opening the app in fullscreen modes through (add to homescreen) vimeo will not play any more. It get's stuck on loading the movie.

Anybody run into the same problem or any suggestions why this may be the case?

Thnx!

Comment: Hi Craig, unfortunately not. Had to add a 'video not working, click here' link to it, with link to the browser app.

Comment: Sounds like the best work around I've heard of so far